# How to add kubernates ingress and eggres rules

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am newbie to Kubernetes, and I need to add some rules to the network policy:

- Allow ingress traffic from the list of predefined IP addresses to specific ports.
- Deny ingress traffic from private subnets.
- Allow egress traffic to the Internet.
- Deny egress traffic to private subnets.

I found some documents, but I couldn't find for internet. 
And finally, how can I write this policy with Kubernetes java library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes Network Policy is designed to restrict access inside the cluster, limiting access from pods to another pods and services.

- [Network Policies](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)
- [Declare Network Policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/declare-network-policy/)

If you need to restrict access from/to internet, it's better to use cloud provider capabilities or a physical device like:

- routers (Cisco, Juniper)
- [load balancer/application delivery controllers(ADC)](https://www.serverwatch.com/server-tutorials/slideshows/11-load-balancers-you-need-to-know-in-2016.html) (f5 BIG-IP, Cisco)
- security appliance (Fortinet, Cisco ASA, Check Point)

To manage Kubernetes from java code you can use [official java client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java).